# Find all solutions of $\ddot x+x^{2021}=0$ that converge

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

From an exam for my first course on ODEs:

> Find all solutions of $$\ddot x+x^{2021}=0$$ such that the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty} x(t)$ exists.

---

I am stuck on this problem. I can't solve this equation. I have tried to set

$$ \begin{aligned}  \dot x  &=  y \\ \dot y &= -x^{2021} \end{aligned} $$

and got $$ H(x,y) = y^{2}+\frac{x^{2022}}{1011} $$ but I don't know how to continue from here, and how the fact that the limit exists help me.

Comment: Where is this from? What have you learned about ODEs?

Comment: why introducing y at all?

Comment: So now you have $\dot{x}^2+x^{2022}/1011=C$. If $x$ has a limit at infinity, then, probably, $\dot{x}$ also has a limit at infinity.

Comment: What is this $H$ ?

Comment: The only solution with the limit is $x(t)=0$, all other solutions are periodic (since they are on the level sets of your $H$).

Comment: I understand that the all other solutions are on the level sets of H but why this implies that they are periodic?  - @Artem

Comment: Level sets of $H$ look like "ellipses", they are closed curves. To closed curves correspond periodic solutions (this is a basic fact for autonomous diff equations based on the translation invariance of solutions, i.e., if $x(t)$ is a solution then $x(t+h)$ is also a solution for any $h$)

Comment: @Artem I would say you have enough material for an answer.